# RxJs retry after run another observable

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I implement refresh token with Redux epic and RxJs. This my code

```
const accountGetSubscription = (action$) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(ACCOUNT_GET_SUBSCRIPTION),
    mergeMap((action) => {
      return accountService.getSubscription().pipe(
        map((res) => {
          if (res.data.data) {
            return setStatusSubscriptionAction(res.data.data)
          } else {
            return setStatusSubscriptionAction(false);
          }
        }),
        catchError((error,source) => {
           return from(refreshToken()).pipe(
              mergeMap(() => source),
              catchError(() => of(setStatusSubscriptionAction(false)))
            )
        })
      );
    })
  );
};

const refreshToken = () => {
  const data = {
    refresh_token : localStorageService.get("refresh_token")
  }
  return accountService.getNewToken(data).pipe(
    tap((res) => {
      lsService.set("account", res.data.access_token)
    })
  )
}
```

My expectation when get error execute `refreshToken()` then retry the current observable, but this code only execute `refreshToken()` not retry the current observable.

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz?

Comment: Do you keep any information about the refresh token in the Redux store? If yes, the `state$` observable (second argument to the Epic) could be a great way to listen and kick of a retry.